# Problemas com FreqDist e ConditionalFreqDist do NLTK

Tags: nltk

Tokenizei e tagueei uma coluna do Pandas com o nltk e, depois, exportei minha coluna como uma lista.
`list1 = esquizo['Enunciados_limpos'].apply(lambda x: nltk.word_tokenize(x)).apply(lambda x: modelo_treinado.tag(x)).tolist()`.
Essa list1 tem a seguinte estrutura (tem mais de mil delas, esse é apenas um exemplo):
`[[('minha', 'PROADJ'), ('infância', 'N'), ('na', 'ADV'), ('Bahia', 'NPROP'), ('era', 'V'), ('boa', 'ADJ'), ('mas', 'KC'), ('era', 'V'), ('sofrida', 'PCP'), ('também', 'PDEN'), ('né', 'IN'), ('doutor', 'N'), ('Oswaldo', 'NPROP')], [('porque', 'KS'), ('eu', 'PROPESS'), ('tinha', 'V')]],`
Agora eu tô tentando usar `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist` e`nltk.FreqDist'`  na list1 num for loop, mas quero os resultados baseados no texto todo, não por listas/tuplas. Tentei:
`fd = [] cd = [] for tuple in list1: fd.append(nltk.FreqDist(tuple)) cd.append(nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(tuple))`
E obtenho para cd(ConditionalFreqDist) e fd(FreqDist) (mostro apenas um pois é o mesmo problema)

> 

```
[ConditionalFreqDist(nltk.probability.FreqDist,
                     {'Bahia': FreqDist({'NPROP': 1}),
                      'Oswaldo': FreqDist({'NPROP': 1}),
                      'boa': FreqDist({'ADJ': 1}),
                      'doutor': FreqDist({'N': 1}),
                      'era': FreqDist({'V': 2}),
                      'infância': FreqDist({'N': 1}),
                      'mas': FreqDist({'KC': 1}),
                      'minha': FreqDist({'PROADJ': 1}),
                      'na': FreqDist({'ADV': 1}),
                      'né': FreqDist({'IN': 1}),
                      'sofrida': FreqDist({'PCP': 1}),
                      'também': FreqDist({'PDEN': 1})}),
 ConditionalFreqDist(nltk.probability.FreqDist,
                     {'a': FreqDist({'ART': 1}),
                      'avô': FreqDist({'N': 1}),
                      'em': FreqDist({'PREP': 1}),
                      'era': FreqDist({'V': 1}),
                      'eu': FreqDist({'PROPESS': 3})})
```

Pergunto: é possível usar o FreqDist e o ConditionalFreqDist na list1 contando o texto todo, não por listas/tuplas? Como eu faria isso? No pandas eu tentei com uma lambda (esquizo['Enunciados_limpos'].apply(lambda x: nltk.word_tokenize(x)).apply(lambda x: modelo_treinado.tag(x)).apply(lambda x: nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(x))`, mas o resultado é por linha e não pela coluna inteira (que representaria o texto todo, no caso). Ou seja, não consegui nem com a list1 nem no dataframe! OBrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar o FreqDist vc tem que iterar por todas as palavras do set.

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.probability import FreqDist

>>> sent = 'Eu quero analisar isso.'

>>> fdist = FreqDist()
>>> for word in word_tokenize(sent):
...    fdist[word.lower()] += 1
```

Sendo assim, você teria que iterar linha por linha do seu dataframe e depois dento de sua coluna

Algo como abaixo:

```
for key, value in df.iterrows():
    for tupla in value["sua_coluna_aqui"]:
        fdist[tupla[0]] += 1  # Sua palavra
```

**ARUALIZAÇÃO - 2020/12/3 - de acordo com o comentário**

De acordo com seu post, os dados são:

```
minha_lista = [ [('o', 'TAG1'), ('exemplo', 'TAG2')], [('um', 'TAG3'), ('exemplo', 'TAG2')], [('sem', 'TAG4'), ('exemplo', 'TAG2')] ]
```

Podemos então colocar em uma estrutura pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"sentence": minha_lista})
```

O dataframe neste momento é:

```
>>> df
                         sentence
0    [(o, TAG1), (exemplo, TAG2)]
1   [(um, TAG3), (exemplo, TAG2)]
2  [(sem, TAG4), (exemplo, TAG2)]
```

Basta então calcular a freqüência:

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

fdist = FreqDist()

for key, value in df.iterrows():
    for tupla in value["sentence"]:
        fdist[tupla[0]] += 1
        print(tupla[0])  # Imprime a palavra só para confirmar que não está fazendo nada errado. :)
```

A saída será:

```
o
exemplo
um
exemplo
sem
exemplo
```

Checando a freqüência:

print(fdist)
FreqDist({'exemplo': 3, 'o': 1, 'um': 1, 'sem': 1})

```
Espero que ajude
```

Comment: O primeiro código, com exemplo de "eu quero analisar isso'', não funciona com a estrutura que tenho, que não é string, mas tuplas dentro de listas. No segundo, do Pandas, fdist faz contagens por caracteres e não por palavras. Obrigado pela ajuda, de qualquer forma.

Comment: @JuniorCosta - Atualizei o post frente ao seu comentário.

Comment: obrigado! Funcionou para o FreqDist. Vou ver se subo outra pergunta só com a Conditional Freq Dist, pois pra ela eu ainda não consegui fazer por toda a estrutura (tal como você acabou de me ensinar sobre o Freq Dist) e não apenas pelas sublistas com tuplas que compõem os dados. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @JuniorCosta, que bom que funcionou. Achando pertinente, marque a resposta. :)

Comment: Marquei agora. Tinha me esquecido. Sou novo aqui. Obrigado mesmo!